# Facebook Like Button Android native

Tags: android

Hi i have been trying to find how to add the like button to my android code. i have done the following things can anyone help me out it always throw me this error

```
 {Response:  responseCode: 403, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions}, isFromCache:false}
```

**i have added the publish permission in my request as wel. my code below:**

```
public void doLike(Session session, String Id) {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("object", "http://graph.facebook.com/" + Id);
    // /* make the API call */
     new Request(session, "/me/og.likes", params, HttpMethod.POST,
     new Request.Callback() {
     public void onCompleted(Response response) {
    // /* handle the result */
     System.out.println(response);
     }
     }).executeAsync();
```

}

```
{Request:  session: {Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[publish_actions, publish_stream]}, appId:xxxxxx}, graphPath: /me/og.likes, graphObject: null, restMethod: null, httpMethod: POST, parameters: Bundle[{access_token=CAAT0aKyquLEBAOxF4XYENsZBFLdD7ZALvGOvQ25ZAvGl6vmCPz8AHOQcZAnKHaOOYPv4DkL0VlMu7jveZCjmht20MuB7qLWpUZAo2DPQxG16ZAF5ICouzAbwpKmMmJdEF1HN1MzCLp5GhlYyy4f63WL5wUE21wRKiYg8wJVy3AGlATcDjpU4FyZB64dZCDv66zv228ZCsuemiFIqf5Qqwcb1QIca91WfCCDZCh71ZCz9CXegCvt1CBurddDo, format=json, object=http://graph.facebook.com/xxxx, sdk=android}]}
```

this is my request but still getting the error

Comment: you also need to set permission in your app setting

Comment: Biraj u mean to say i need to set permission in developers.facebook.com?

Comment: yes it is call extended permissions, did you set that?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the screenshot and check did you set the above permissions?

[image]

Comment: i am still getting that after setting the permission too.. kindly help me

Comment: also add the permission "publish_stream" in your code

Comment: Biraj i have edited my quest and added request to it.. but still i am facing the problem do help me